# How to change the default appearance of amarok in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, amarok

I started using amarok initially when i used Kubuntu and since then I've not seen any reason to drop it, so i switched to Ubuntu and installed amarok but the only problem i have is that i don't like the default orange appearance(i know it's trying to take the Ubuntu look) i've searched and googled how to change it to some other color maybe blue but I've not seen any answer and it's not under settings in amarok either. please how do i do this

Answer (score 1):

Well, Amarok was originally developed under KDE and maybe in Kubuntu it was easier for you to change themes but still you can try these solutions one of them should work:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install kcontrol
```

if it didn't work then try:

```
sudo apt-get install systemsettings
```

After this you should be able to configure KDE apps.